# how to adjust all spaces between pictures to be exactly the same

Tags: html, css

All my pictures must meet the following criteria:

1). Whenever using computer or cell phone to view, must appear 4 items on same line, without RWD function.
2) No matter what the height and width measurements all outer frame must be identical, I spent days to adjust like this, but I found distance from picture to picture (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fsUN5ms1U4hfSoXl-oNcvEiwBwfVNpoZ/view?usp=sharing) are different, please advise how to adjust all spaces between pictures to be exactly the same.

Another question is how to control ever line's spacing?  If I key in xxx, every line's space height will be too wide, need to shrink the height, I still cannot solve through setting, can anyone lend a helping hand?  Appreciate it very much.[problem][1]
[website URL](http://www.ecotw.com.tw/vicky/tsai/titbit.html)

```
<table class="table table-borderless" style="margin:0px 0px;" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div id="container"><img style="border:1px #000 solid;padding:5px;text-align:center;" src="content/images/demo/001.jpg"></div>
    <p class="text-center">xxx</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div id="container"><img style="border:1px #000 solid;padding:5px;text-align:center;" src="content/images/demo/002.jpg"></div>
    <p class="text-center">xxx</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div id="container" style="border:1px #000 solid;padding:5px;text-align:center;"><img src="content/images/demo/003.jpg"></div>
    <p class="text-center">xxx</p>                              
    </td>
    <td>
    <div id="container" style="border:1px #000 solid;padding:5px;text-align:center;"><img src="content/images/demo/004.jpg"></div>
    <p class="text-center">xxx</p>                              
    </td>                           
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div style="border:1px #000 solid;padding:5px;text-align:center;"><img src="content/images/demo/005.jpg"></div>
    <p class="text-center">xxx</p>                              
    </td>
    <td>
    <div style="border:1px #000 solid;padding:5px;text-align:center;"><img src="content/images/demo/006.jpg"></div>
    <p class="text-center">xxx</p>                              
    </td>
    <td>
    <div style="border:1px #000 solid;padding:5px;text-align:center;"><img src="content/images/demo/007.jpg"></div>
    <p class="text-center">xxx</p>                              
    </td>
    <td>
    <div style="border:1px #000 solid;padding:5px;text-align:center;"><img src="content/images/demo/008.jpg"></div>
    <p class="text-center">xxx</p>                              
    </td>                           
    </tr>                           
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div style="border:1px #000 solid;padding:5px;text-align:center;"><img src="content/images/demo/009.jpg"></div>
    <p class="text-center">xxx</p>                              
    </td>
    <td>
    <div style="border:1px #000 solid;padding:5px;text-align:center;"><img src="content/images/demo/010.jpg"></div>
    <p class="text-center">xxx</p>                              
    </td>                           
    </tr>                               
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using table.
You should be using the grid layout.
[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) is a great guide.

EDIT:

#### Does this work for you?

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  /* Use % instead of px for it to be proportionnal to the frame width */
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20%;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.grid-item>img{
  /* make it so the image take up the whole grid-item width */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
    <span class="author-span">AUTHOR_name</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
    <span class="author-span">AUTHOR_name</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
    <span class="author-span">AUTHOR_name</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
    <span class="author-span">AUTHOR_name</span>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    IMAGE
    <span class="author-span">AUTHOR_name</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
    <span class="author-span">AUTHOR_name</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
    <span class="author-span">AUTHOR_name</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
    <span class="author-span">AUTHOR_name</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
    <span class="author-span">AUTHOR_name</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
    <span class="author-span">AUTHOR_name</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
    <span class="author-span">AUTHOR_name</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to put author's name beneath the picture which doesn't need this height?
Does this need to set up separately?

Auto will let the distance  of each picture 
different as I have both horizontal and 
vertical ones.  If I set up the frame by 250px, the screen will override screen on cell phone.
How to zoom or shrink the frame proportionally view by different screen size?

Comment: @VickyLee I didn't really understand  the 'which doesn't need this height' . I edited my post.